# Django: multiple models with one-to-many relation on admin page TabularInline

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have multiple models in an existing database that all have a many-to-one relation to another model. For example:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
        start = models.DateTimeField()
        end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'Program'

class ItemA(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        'Collection', models.CASCADE, db_column='Collection_id')
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ItemA'

class ItemB(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        'Collection', models.CASCADE, db_column='Collection_id')
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ItemB'
```

What I want to do, is show these models in a single `TabularInline` on the admin page of the Collection model. I also want to be able to filter the models. Is this possible without inheritance in the database? (I don't want to add a general item table). In the documentation, I can only find how you can use TabularInline for a single model. So my question is basically: What would be the best approach to solve this? Is it maybe possible to define some kind of view model dat is not in the database, but that can be used to display all the items in a `TabularInline`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a view in my database, meaning that I did not need to add a table. In Django, I created a model to handle the view:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        'Collection', models.CASCADE, db_column='Collection_id')
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Item' # This is not a table, but a view
```

I defined the View by using multiple `SELECT` statements and `UNION`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `Item` AS
SELECT CONCAT('itemA_',id) as id, name, ... FROM ItemA 
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('itemB_',id) as id, name, ... FROM ItemB
...
```